# android comment box shared preferences struggle

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Hi i have 2 edit text views for name and comment in order to allow a user to add his name and his comment. I have 2 buttons as well 1 for add comment and another one for view comment. My code seems to be working fine but I just don't get what I need. If I click on view comment button, the comment is shown but if I re run the app, the comment is not there. Is there any possible way to make the comment appear even if I re run my app ? Here is my code. Please help. This is my first activity.

```
    public class addreview extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferencesFile";

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reviews);

    final EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText review = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonreview);
    Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonviewreview);
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new  
  Intent(getApplicationContext(),addreview2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }



    });



    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        SharedPreferences settings  = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("name" , name.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("review" , review.getText().toString());

        editor.commit();



        }
```

And my second activity is.

```
    public class addreview2 extends Activity {
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferencesFile";

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.review2);
    TextView tvname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    TextView tvreview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewReview);

    SharedPreferences settings  = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);

    tvname.setText(settings.getString("name","Eddie"));
    tvreview.setText(settings.getString("review","review1"));
     SharedPreferences preferences = 
 PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      String name = preferences.getString("name","");
   }
}
```

Can Someone tell me what I have to do to make the comment appear even if I rerun the application ? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Which activity are you unable to see the comment in when rerunning the app?

Comment: In the second one, when I click the button show reviews it doesn't display my previous comment.